# simplify web front-end development

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I have developed some web projects, to me, the back-end part is clear & easy, but the front-end part is complex & time assuming, because make a page dynamic & smart need write a lot javascript & css, especially when need to make some components like grid / tree / form validation.

I hope to simplify the process of front-end development, I have used jqueryUI/extjs, extjs is very powerful but heavy & complex, jqueryUI is simple but not enough. I also checked angularJs a little, but it feels defined a new language, and I like it because it makes html grammar like a jsp/php file.

Currently, for management system I use extjs, for web system that face users I use js/css/jqueryUI, but I still don't feel it's simple enough, especially when I write js/css, there are too much code.

So what is your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommend AngularJS for your solution. Jquery is not enough for building complex web applications.

I would argue against `feel boring & stupid when using it`. Angular JS is a very powerful framework for building scaleable webapps. Its learning curve is steep though that might explain you feel bored and stupid.

For CSS, go for either LESS or SASS pre-processors.

http://lesscss.org/

http://sass-lang.com/

All of this should be coupled with grunt.js to minify and build all your artifacts.

Comment: This is useful to me, I don't know why those people close my question.

Comment: Your question was closed because it was very open ended. It should be specific. Too much code, boring , stupid are not right arguments for not developing a solution in particular technology

Comment: So, if I have an open question, I shouldn't come to here?

Comment: No. SO is meant for specific questions related to programming. I would turn to google or http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ for such questions.

Comment: Hey, I check AngularJS a little recent days, it's pretty good, I apology for say something bad on it. Just the official tutorial is too complex, it should not use npm at beginning, should use it at least after introduct the basic feature, because many people don't use nodejs, thus no npm too, they should not mix them together at the very beginning.

Comment: I find this pretty good .... http://www.amazon.com/AngularJS-Brad-Green/dp/1449344852/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1406209359&sr=8-2&keywords=angularjs